# Alignment of an image

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Is it possible to align a point of an image against a marker outside of the image environment?

Suppose I have an image and then a paragraph. Is it possible to have a marker X in the paragraph and align the center of the image against that marker (for example 1 cm to right of X)?

If not, how do I position an image at say center+1cm  instead of at  center?

Edit

I see that I can put a shift  as in

```
  \quad \includegraphics
```

to effect movement.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See TikZ manual, pp. 249.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can save the x (and y) coordinate on the page and use that in a calculation elsewhere. Under pdfLaTeX you can use [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module to perform expandable calculations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,zref-savepos}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

Exact centre of text block:

\rule{.5\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
\end{center}

\rule{.5\textwidth}{1pt}

\hfill\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-b}\hfill\mbox{}

\hrulefill

1cm to the right of the text block centre:

\rule{\dimexpr.5\textwidth+1cm}{1pt}

\begin{center}
  \hspace{2cm}\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
\end{center}

\rule{\dimexpr.5\textwidth+1cm}{1pt}

\hfill\hspace{2cm}\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-b}\hfill\mbox{}

\hrulefill

At the same location as some marker within a paragraph:

\noindent% Start a paragraph (if needed)
\zsaveposx{leftmargin}%
\hspace{\dimexpr\zposx{Xmarker}sp-\zposx{leftmargin}sp}%
\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor sit amet 
ante sed X\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1cm}\zsaveposx{Xmarker}} molestie. Proin scelerisque 
accumsan efficitur. Nulla sagittis nibh non ultrices gravida. Proin id diam et dolor 
iaculis lacinia id non felis.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In these three case, I us `\tclap` (top-center lap) to place the above image right after the `!` of `NOW!`.  In the first case, the image is centered to the right hand edge of the `!`, while in the 2nd and 3rd cases, the 2cm image is moved 1cm to the right of the `!`, resulting in an image left aligned to the right-hand edge of `!`.

In the 3rd case, since the marker was not in the first line of the paragraph, additional tricks (`\smash` and `\vspace`) were added to accomplish the task.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\def\IG{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
\begin{document}
Here is text. 
Here is text. 
Here is text.NOW!\tclap{\IG}
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. \smallskip

Here is text. 
Here is text. 
Here is text.NOW!\tclap{\hspace{2cm}\IG}
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. \vspace{4\baselineskip}

Here is text. 
Here is text. 
Here is text.
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text.%
NOW!\smash{\tclap[4\baselineskip]{\hspace{2cm}\IG}}
Here is text. Here is text. 
Here is text. 
\end{document}
```

[image]